# how do I attach 2 wires to one terminal screw on an outlet or light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm in the USA.  I often need to attach 2 wires to 1 screw terminal -- for instance on a switch... or on a single outlet... or a duplex outlet that I've split.

What are my options to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain wires must be pigtailed, you can't rely on the device to make the connection.  That includes all grounds.  It also includes neutrals in *multi-wire branch circuits*.

If it has 2 screw terminals obviously ganged together, you can use those.  These are often connected by "tabs" which can be broken off to change the device's function -- watch out for those.

It is illegal to put 2 wires on one screw.

If it has the higher quality back connection which is clamped by the screw, those commonly provide for 2 wires per screw, so you're all set.

If it has 2 backstab holes obviously together, well... try to avoid using "backstabs" *at all* as they are not reliable.

It is illegal to use one screw and one backstab.  Use only one kind of fastening method.

If all else fails, obtain a "wire nut" - similar to the ones you may see on the neutral and ground wire.  Nut the 2 wires together with a third wire about 6" long.  This is called a "pigtail".

Comment: You should clarify that this applies to the USA (and possibly Canada) only and not to any countries in Europe (as far as I know).

Comment: *It is illegal to put 2 wires on one screw.* - cite?

Comment: @Mazura NEC 110.14. See [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/5551/47125).